# How to express the number of subjects in a proposition by using predicates?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

Let F(x,y) be the statement "x can fool y," where the domain consists of all people in the world.

```
∃y1∃y2 (F(Nancy,y1) ∧ F(Nancy,y2) ∧ y1 ≠ y2 ∧ ∀y(F(Nancy,y) → (y=y1 ∨ y=y2)))
```

Why this proposition denotes:  Nancy can fool exactly **two** people.

I do not understand the way that we are using with quantifier to denote number of people.

To express the same meaning, can I say this instead:

```
∃y1∃y2 (F(Nancy,y1) ∧ F(Nancy,y2) ∧ y1 ≠ y2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second proposition is not equivalent, because it does not limit the number of people Nancy can fool. There may exist a $y_3$ not equal to $y_1$ or $y_2$ such that $F(\textrm{Nancy},y_3)$ is true.

The statement $\forall y : F(\textrm{Nancy},y) \Rightarrow (y = y_1 \lor y = y_2)$ means that if $F(\textrm{Nancy},y)$ holds, either $y$ is $y_1$ or $y$ is $y_2$. In other words, if Nancy can fool person $y$, either $y$ is person $y_1$ or person $y_2$. Or, equivalently, if person $y$ is not $y_1$ or $y_2$, Nancy cannot fool $y$. The rest of the proposition establishes that $y_1$ and $y_2$ can both be fooled by Nancy, and $y_1$ and $y_2$ are two different people. Hence, Nancy can fool exactly two people.

Comment: Does the second proposition shows that Nancy can fool two people in the world? Like, any two people.

The first proposition shows that Nancy can fool two people, but they are two specific people in the world instead of any two people?

Comment: No, because the $\exists y_1 \exists y_2$ specifies the existence of two specific people $y_1$ and $y_2$. This does not imply that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are any two arbitrary people. For example, you could say that $\exists x (x^2 = 0)$ but this does not imply that the square of real number $x$ is equal to zero, but rather that there is at least one real number whose square is zero.

Comment: so how to express this in English?
`∃y1∃y2 (F(Nancy,y1) ∧ F(Nancy,y2) ∧ y1 ≠ y2)`

Comment: There are two distinct people that Nancy can fool. Typically if you said something like this you would imply that there are *only* two people, but in propositional logic that isn't necessarily true. If there are three people that Nancy can fool, Nancy can also fool two people. Does that make sense?

Comment: I see! Therefore, if Nancy can fool three people, this proposition still holds. If I use the first proposition, it limits Nancy can only fool exactly two people?

Comment: Yes, basically. That's what the extra statement adds, essentially.

Comment: @Fan `∃y1∃y2 (F(Nancy,y1) ∧ F(Nancy,y2) ∧ y1 ≠ y2)`. Nancy can fool at least two different people